# Why does my $timeout.cancel work here, but not here?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having a strange problem in my Angular app.

In the sidebar I have some tags with code to show a hover and hide a hover. It requires the user sit over the tag for 2 secs before the hover is shown, if the user leaves before 2 secs, the `$timeout.cancel` will wire in the `mouseleave` function and kill it. So it works great.

However in another directive this does not happen, I basically/90% have the exact same code, however the `$timeout.cancel` is completely ignored, so as soon as you hover over a tag in this other directive, after 2 secs the hover will fire no matter what.

**Working code (tagsPanel Directive)**

```
function hoverTag(tag) {
    vs.hoverTimeout = $timeout(function() {
        ApiFactory.getTagDataSilm(tag.term_id).then(function(data) {
            console.log('getTagDataSilm: ', data.data.ticker_tag);
            tag.tickers = data.data.ticker_tag.tickers;
            tag.tagsHoverDisplay = true; 
        });
    }, 2000);
}

function leaveTag(tag) {
    $timeout.cancel(vs.hoverTimeout);
    tag.tagsHoverDisplay = false;
}
```

Working markup

```
<li ng-repeat="t in tags" ng-class="{'selected': t.selected}">
    <div class="tag-container-container">
        <div class="tag-container"
             ng-class="{'width-auto': widthAuto}"
             ng-mouseleave="leaveTag(t)">
            <div class="tag"
                 ng-click="selectTag(t)"
                 ng-mouseover="hoverTag(t)"
                 ng-class="{'positive': t.direction == 'positive',
                            'negative': t.direction == 'negative',
                            ''        : t.direction == 'stagnant'}">
                            {{t.term}}
            </div>
            <tags-hover tag="t"></tags-hover>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**NOT working code (viewHeader Directive)**

```
function hoverViewTag(ticker, tag) {
    console.log('hoverViewTag ', tag);
    vs.hoverViewTimeout = $timeout(function() {

        ApiFactory.getTagData(ticker, tag.term_id).then(function(data) {
            var timeSpan = TimeSpanFactory.getTimeSpan();
            var period   = createSortString(timeSpan.when);
            var singleTagArray = [];
            singleTagArray.push(data.data.ticker_tag);
            var tagDetails = TagFactory.renderDirections(singleTagArray, null, period);

            tag.tagsHoverDisplay         = true;
            tag.favorite                 = tagDetails[0].favorite;
            tag.quantity                 = tagDetails[0].quantity;
            tag.tickers                  = tagDetails[0].tickers;
            tag.tweet_percentage         = tagDetails[0].tweet_percentage;
            tag.momentum_twitter_preview = tagDetails[0].momentum_twitter_preview;
        });
    }, 2000);
}

function leaveViewTag(tag) {
    // Cancel damn it!
    $timeout.cancel(vs.hoverViewTimeout);
    tag.tagsHoverDisplay = false;
}
```

NOT working markup (timeout will fire despite mouseleave function)

```
<ul class="view-tags-ul" ng-repeat="obj in vh.viewTickerTags">
    <li ng-repeat="t in obj.tags track by $index">
        <div class="tag-container"
             ng-mouseleave="vh.leaveViewTag(t)">
            <div class="tag"
                 ng-click="vh.removeTag(obj.ticker, t)"
                 ng-mouseover="vh.hoverViewTag(obj.ticker, t)"
                 ng-class="{'positive': t.direction == 'positive',
                            'negative': t.direction == 'negative',
                            ''        : t.direction == 'stagnant'}">{{t.term}}
                <div class="close-x-sml"></div>
            </div>
            <tags-hover tag="t"></tags-hover>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Extras

This is what `tags` looks like in the tagsPanel scope:

[image]

This is what the `vh.viewTickerTags` object looks like:

[image]

---

CSS for `.tag`

```
.tag {
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid $gray_light;
    background: $gray_bg;

    &:hover {
        -webkit-transition : border 2000ms ease-out; 
        -moz-transition : border 2000ms ease-out;
        -o-transition : border 2000ms ease-out;
        border: 1px solid $gray4 !important;
        background: #fff !important;
    }

    &.positive,
    &.negative { border: 1px solid $gray2; }

    &.positive:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        right: 0;
        @include triangle(left, 10px, $green);
    }

    &.negative:after {
        position: absolute;
        right: -10px;
        bottom: 0;
        @include triangle(up, 10px, $red);
    }

    &.blue1 { @include colored-tag($blue1) }
    &.blue2 { @include colored-tag($blue2) }
    &.blue3 { @include colored-tag($blue3) }
}

li.selected {
    .tag {
        font-family: 'robotoregular';
        border: 1px solid $gray4;
    }
}
```

CSS for `.tag` inside of the `viewHeader` scope

```
.viewing-tags {
    margin-left: 20px;

    span {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        top: 2px;
        font-style: Condensed;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: em(10);
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .ticker { margin-right: 0; }

    .tags-hover-container {
        .ticker { margin-right: 5px; }
    }

    .tag { margin-right: 0; padding-right: 0px; }
    .tag { padding-bottom: 6px; }
    .tag {
        max-width: auto !important;
        width: auto !important;
        border: 1px solid $gray4 !important;
        background: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: note, you have a div inside the div you have the mouseover event on, and the mouseover event will trigger when you mouse over either of those two divs. So it's certainly possible that you have two timers going, one of which is not stoppable due to losing reference to the ID. More debugging is needed to see if this is indeed the case. One quick test would be to replace mouseover with mouseenter, which will only trigger once in the above scenario.

Comment: Yes, the reason I have a div inside a div, is because of `tagHover` which comes up is inside the container div. The user needs to be able to hover over the actual `tagHover` once it's shown, without closing it as soon as they roll off the tag button which activated it.

Comment: Right, but that causes the possibility of starting a 2nd timer, before the first is canceled, thus making the first impossible to stop.

Comment: You can test my above theory by adding logging statements inside of each of your event handlers. if the mouseover happens more times than the mouseleave, that's your problem.

Comment: @KevinB something strange is going on, when I quickly hover over and off 1 tag, I see 2 logs for `hoverViewTag` and 1 log for `leaveViewTag`. No idea why the first would fire twice... hmmm

Comment: Can you provide css for div class=tag and it's children?

Comment: Try the suggestion I mentioned in first comment, of simply replacing ng-mouseover with ng-mouseenter.

Comment: OH shoot, I miss read that, that FIXED it! :D :D hmmm need to read up on what the difference is now

Comment: That confirms it then. what's happening is when you mouse over the div, you're also mousing over one of it's children, thus triggering the event twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second (non-working) example, the div has children, and since you're using *mouseover*, the event handler will run each time you hover over a child of that div.

To fix this, simply replace `ng-mouseover` with `ng-mouseenter`, which differs from *mouseover* in that it will trigger when you enter the div, but not when you hover over one of it's children. It's the opposite of *mouseleave*. The opposite of *mouseover* is *mouseout*.